# Is there a test for the timing of non-stationarity?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, change-point

I am wondering whether a test exists that identifies at which point in time a time series becomes non-stationary. For instance, a time series might fulfill all requirements for weak stationariy in the first year and then explodes. I am working on data for which it would be interesting to know at which point in time the time series is "exploding".

Cheers
Ralf

Comment: Could you explain what "explodes" means in this context. The word evokes a good visual, but does not exactly say what happens numerically. What does happen numerically, please?

Comment: Stationarity is a subtle property and generally cannot be localized.  Perhaps you are looking for more manifest abrupt changes, such as a [tag:change-point] or [tag:structural-change]?

Comment: thank you very much for your answers...@Carl: With explode I mean the point in time of after which a test for stationarity would be rejected, but I think I will follow the suggestion made by @whuber. Thanks anyways!